# Issue with JavaScript frogger-based game

Tags: javascript

I am developing a Frogger-based game in JavaScript, and have managed to randomly generate an enemy from a choice of 2 `const names = ['gannon', 'robot']`, which appears on a random div on my grid because I used `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100`. Now I am trying to adapt this so multiple random enemies will show on each of the following div’s on my grid only: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 and 80.

Do you know how I can adapt my JavaScript to do this?

Here's a link to my current functionality: http://digilia.co.uk/

```
  // Function - Random Enememy
  function getRandomEnemyName() {
    const names = ['gannon', 'robot']
    return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)]
  }

  // Function = Game Logic
  function startGame() {
    enemyPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    randomEnemy = getRandomEnemyName()
    cells[enemyPosition].classList.add(randomEnemy)
  }

  let enemyPosition = 0
  let randomEnemy = getRandomEnemyName()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what's your question: do you want to limit to 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 and 80 the cell where you can put an enemy? In that case you just have to randomly choose a number between 1…8 included and then multiply by 10… Otherwise I didn't get the question.

Comment: Please try to describe your issue instead of wrting the scenario or problem. For example, You could have asked this question like: How to get random number from perticular set of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a random number between ***min*** and ***max*** value using below method:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
```

Here, you want any random number between 0 and 9. So, min value would be 1 and max value would be 9 ( Because we are using Math.floor). After that multiply the number you got with 10 and you will get your output. Any random number from 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80.

```
function startGame() {
    enemyPosition = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1) + 1)) * 10;
    randomEnemy = getRandomEnemyName()
    cells[enemyPosition].classList.add(randomEnemy)
  }
```